# What's the difference between bytes() and bytearray() when writing over serial?

Tags: python, pyserial, rs485

I've been pulling my hair out for a few days now trying to figure out what was wrong with my program. Here's an example:

**Input:**

```
rsBus = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600, timeout = 1)


commandArray = bytearray([0x23, 0x24])
commandByte = bytes([0x23, 0x24])



rsBus.write(commandArray)
print(rsBus.read(1))



rsBus.write(commandByte)
print(rsBus.read(1))
```

**Output:**

```
b''
b'A'
```

Now, with the equipment I'm working with, if it receives a valid packet it will send a reply packet. If it receives anything else at all, it will send nothing at all. So, with that said, why do I not get a reply when I use `bytearray()` but I do when I use `bytes()`? As far as I know the only difference between the two is that `bytearray()` is mutable whereas `bytes()` is not. Is there more to it than that?

Python 3.10

Comment: You should mention which version of Python you're using.  `01` isn't a valid number in Python 3.

Comment: Sorry, I've been dealing with hex all day, and just typed this up real quick. I've edited it to be ```1``` now.

Comment: If you swap the order of `commandArray` and `commandByte` do you get different results?

Comment: You might want to try your example in another version of Python as PySerial doesn't test at 3.10. https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/633

Comment: @MarkRansom I should clarify, this is just an example to show the two different ways I tried. In practice, I either run ```commandByte``` OR ```commandArray``` each time.

Comment: I find it suspicious that you get back an empty string.  Try a longer timeout.

Comment: Try it with `bytes(commandArray)`.